# LCD laptop display is greyed out on startup

Tags: lcd, start-screen, hp-elitebook, defective-hardware

I have just a small display problem with my laptop (HP Elitebook 8440p) running on Debian 8. Whenever the computer is booting up from sleep, my screen will either be flashing pixels everywhere, or be grey out up to about half a cm to the top. But then it would snap down and reveal the normal screen after about ten minutes. Keep in mind that the HP startup screen does load everytime before doing this. Could it be the inverter? Or a wrong current going in? I really do hope it's not the backlight or anything like that :/

Comment: try to plug an external monitor and play with it. You'll know if its at least your screen or your computer like your debian. but it sounds like your screen itself if you ask me.

Comment: @LateGameReviewer I think it is the screen also. The Hdmi out does work on my tv but when I switch to another tv sometimes it won't show on either tv.